# NG-STYLE is not working in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

> message.viewed is a boolean value.I need to change attribute of my message content according to the boolean value.Here I used one method.I did not work for me.

```
<div  ng-style="message.viewed ? {'font-weight': 'bold''} : {'font-weight': 100}" >
<span >{{message.Title}}</span> {{message.details }}
</div>
```

Comment: Any error in the console? And there are two single quotes after `bold`, I guess it's a typo in the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change your `ng-style` to this

```
<div  ng-style="{'font-weight' : message.viewed ? 'bold' : '100'}" >
    <span >{{message.Title}}</span> {{message.details }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you problem was fixed.

Comment: @HRCJ No problem. Don't forget to mark the answer that helped you

Comment: I tried to mark.But I have to wait 10 mins.I'm waiting.

Answer (score 1):

change the ternary condition inside `ng-style` like this

```
 <div  ng-style="{'font-weight': message.viewed ? 'bold' : '100'}" >
<span >{{message.Title}}</span> {{message.details }}
</div>
```

Demo

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

$scope.message = {"viewed":true,"Title":"sample"}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <div  ng-style="{'font-weight': message.viewed ? 'bold' : '100'}" >
<span >{{message.Title}}</span> {{message.details }}
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you problem was fixed.

Comment: @HRCJ no prob  bro :D

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use `[style.fontWeight]` instead of `ng-style` if its a matter of a single property.

```
<div  [style.fontWeight]="message.viewed ? 'bold' : '100'" >
    <span >{{message.Title}}</span> {{message.details }}
</div>
```

Comment: Is this AngularJS v1 valid?

Comment: Thank you problem was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

It would work fine if there is no two single quotes after bold

```
<div ng-style="message.viewed ? {'font-weight': 'bold'} : {'font-weight': 100}">
<span>{{message.Title}}</span> {{message.details }}
```

Comment: Thank you problem was fixed.

Comment: unnecessary use of same property `font-weight` twice

Comment: Yes I know. I was just pointing out syntax error. We can set new style in else part also.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to assign a $scope variable to ng-style

```
$scope.style = message.viewed ? '{'font-weight': 'bold'}' : '{'font-weight': '100'}'
```

Answer (score 0):

assume `message.viewed` expression return true/false so use

```
 ng-style="{font-weight:{ true:'bold', false: 100} [ message.viewed ] }"
```

Comment: Is this AngularJS v1 valid?

Comment: Yes. absolutely

Comment: Interesting, first time I see this notation. Thanks for sharing ;)

Comment: this is helpful when we can apply multiple conditions and classes based on different condition likewise `[ {true:'whetever', flase:'whatelse'}[expression1],{true:'applyifTrue'}[expression2] ]`